# Assign private IP for instances created in google app engine flexible environment

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to create a application in GAE that uses automatic scaling in flexible env. 
The automatic_scaling min instance was set to 2.
Now once the app is deployed the two instances are created and they are assigned public ips.

I also tried specifying the network in app.yml and this creates a private ip for the instance in the network (which is what I want) and I am able to ping the instance with that private IP within the network I mentioned ....but still there is public IP being assigned to the instances

Is there a way to make GAE not assign public ip addresses to the instances?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. From [App Engine FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/):

> Can I access my App Engine instance on a private IP address?
>
> App Engine hosts your service on a dynamic public IP address of a
>   Google load balancer. You can't access your service on private (RFC
>   1918) IP addresses.

If the reason behind your goal is restricting access this may be an approach to consider: [Using the App Engine flexible environment on a Shared VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-shared-vpc)